# Using a mapping table with multiple values per attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

I have been handed a table t_mapping with values such as [1..5],[8..12],15,16 or 17,18 or 20 or [21..45] shown in column **prd_product_nl**. I have to find my values in **prd_product_nl** to look up the **mapping_result** (format: result a, or result b or result c or result d)

The values which I would like to lookup are integers, and the arrays of values in **prd_product_nl**  are in ascending order but are in different formats as shown above.

As a complication, [1..5] means to depict values 1 up and including 5.

Can I write a query which looks up my integers in a column which exists of multiple values in different - array - formats?

Comment: your sample data doesnt make sense. I suggest you provide a SQLFiddle, or atleast format it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by hierarchical queries:

```
with w1(list) as
(
  select '[1..5],[8..12],15,16' from dual
  union all
  select '17,18' from dual
  union all
  select '[21..45]' from dual
),
w2 as
(
  select distinct w1.list, regexp_substr(w1.list, '[^,]+', 1, level) part
  from w1
  connect by regexp_instr(w1.list, '[^,]+', 1, level) != 0
  order by w1.list
),
w3 as
(
  select w2.*,
         regexp_replace(w2.part, '\[(\d+)\.\.(\d+)]', '\1', 1) lower_bound,
         regexp_replace(w2.part, '\[(\d+)\.\.(\d+)]', '\2', 1) upper_bound
  from w2
)
select distinct w3.*, w3.lower_bound + level - 1 item
from w3
connect by level <= w3.upper_bound - w3.lower_bound + 1
order by 1, 5
;
```

This gives:

```
LIST                    PART        LOWER_BOUND    UPPER_BOUND    ITEM
17,18                   17          17             17             17
17,18                   18          18             18             18
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [1..5]      1              5              1
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [1..5]      1              5              2
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [1..5]      1              5              3
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [1..5]      1              5              4
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [1..5]      1              5              5
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [8..12]     8              12             8
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [8..12]     8              12             9
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [8..12]     8              12             10
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [8..12]     8              12             11
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    [8..12]     8              12             12
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    15          15             15             15
[1..5],[8..12],15,16    16          16             16             16
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             21
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             22
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             23
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             24
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             25
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             26
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             27
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             28
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             29
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             30
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             31
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             32
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             33
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             34
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             35
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             36
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             37
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             38
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             39
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             40
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             41
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             42
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             43
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             44
[21..45]                [21..45]    21             45             45
```